# printing alphabets in UILabel

Tags: iphone, uilabel, nstimer

Hai all,
In my iPhone app want to print a series of strings in UILabel one by one,but only the final string is displaying now.
I have tried NSTIMER,but it doesn't work.
can anyone help me.thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
//changing strings to char 
    char *cname1=[n1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    char *cname2=[n2 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


    for (int i = 0; i < [n1 length]; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < [n2 length]; j++){
            if ((cname1[i]==cname2[j]))
            {

                cname1[i]='*';
                cname2[j]='*';

                myString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", cname1];

                myString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", cname2];

                [self printlabel];
                break;
            }


    }

    -(void)printlabel{
        nam1.text = myString1; //set label1
        nam2.text = myString2; //set label2

        }
```

Comment: can you post your relevant code?

Comment: I think you forgot to put some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose, you have 10 `UILabel` in `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray* myAllLabel ;
int labelIndex = 0;
```

Use the below code as reference.

```
- (void) startDisplayingLabel {
     labelIndex = 0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:2.0f target:self selector:@selector(showElapsedTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

`showElapsedTime` will be called after 2.0 second of delay, you provide.

```
-(void) showElapsedTime: (NSTimer *) timer {

    if(labelIndex == 10)
    {
      [timer invalidate];
    }
    else 
    {
         //Now you have your mylabel , you could add it to the superview 
         UILabel* mylabel = (UILabel*)[myAllLabel objectAtIndex:labelIndex];
         // Write your code here 

    }
    labelIndex++;
}
```

Call startDisplayingLabel once, i will display each UILabel after exactly 2.0 second.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [NSThread](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will help you

Try changing your code as,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [n1 length]; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < [n2 length]; j++){
            if ((cname1[i]==cname2[j]))
            {

                cname1[i]='*';
                cname2[j]='*';

                myString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", cname1];

                myString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", cname2];

                [self printlabel];
                break;
            }
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];//sleeps for 2 seconds.
    }
```